# Can we use protractor to test video play,pause and audio?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have an embedded video on a page. When I click on the play icon it opens on JW player. Can protractor be used to test play, pause and audio functions of the video?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a flash player, you can not run assertions on the DOM elements. You can, however, use the player API for assertions:

```
it('it should be possible to play video', function () {
  //play is initially at position 0
  expect(browser.executeScript('jwplayer().getPosition()')).toBe(0);

  $('video-container').click(); //clicks on the middle of the container div starts the diveo
  browser.sleep(2000);
  $('video-container').click(); //clicks on the middle of the container div stops the diveo

  //play has moved its position
  expect(browser.executeScript('jwplayer().getPosition()')).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```